# How to find the next record after a specified one in SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I need to get next 500 records based on values (CompID, TagName, TimeStamp).

Table:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[L_CompDataTest]
(
    [Barcode] [NVARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [CompID] [INT] NULL,
    [TagName] [NVARCHAR](50) NULL,
    [Value] [INT] NULL,
    [TimeStamp] [DATETIME] NULL,
    [CompType] [INT] NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

Query:

```
select * 
from [L_CompDataTest] 
order by TimeStamp desc
```

[image]

I have to get records after this "2019-08-07 13:06:37.760" timestamp using values like  "CompID,TagName,TimeStamp", result should be like this marked in redcolor

[image]

My SQL statement

```
select * 
from [L_CompDataTest] 
where TimeStamp >= '2019-08-07 13:06:37.760' 
  and TagName >= 'Gooseberries2' 
order by TimeStamp desc
```

Output

[image]

I am not able to get expected result as I mentioned in 2) point.

Comment: `TagName >= 'Gooseberries2'` will only return results "after" that word. So `Apple` will not be included. Neither will `Gooseberries1`. Also, I don't think your red selection for expected records is correct either.

Comment: thank u for response,.In client Data there is no transid, help me how to select records after 'Gooseberries2' using timestamp. please check SQL fiddle -http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9a86c7/4/0 .

Comment: Check it for what? Your requirements are not clear, and I don't think you are understanding my comment either... your query returns the results you told it to return, what you are expecting makes no sense.

Comment: What do you mean by "I have to get ever 500 records"?  Are you doing batch processing of some sort?

Answer (score 1):

I think you only need to take the time component into account:

```
select top (500) cdt.*
from L_CompDataTest cdt
where cdt.TimeStamp >= '2019-08-07 13:06:37.760' 
order by cdt.TimeStamp asc;
```

If you then want these ordered differently, use a subquery:

```
select cdt.*
from (select top (500) cdt.*
      from L_CompDataTest cdt
      where cdt.TimeStamp >= '2019-08-07 13:06:37.760' 
      order by cdt.TimeStamp asc
     ) cdt
order by cdt.TimeStamp desc, cdt.tagname;
```

EDIT:

For your particular problem:

```
select top (500) cdt.*
from L_CompDataTest cdt
where cdt.TimeStamp > '2019-08-07 13:06:37.760' OR
      (cdt.TimeStamp = '2019-08-07 13:06:37.760' AND
       cdt.TagName > 'Gooseberries2'
      )
order by cdt.TimeStamp asc;
```

This assumes that the timestamp values are precise.  This can be a little tricky, because SQL Server has enhanced its date/time support, going down to fractions of a millisecond for some types.

Comment: i have to get every 500 records and insert to another sql server, so i have to get data after this record "U3S5C1KH114791098 26 Gooseberries2 0 2019-08-07 13:06:37.760 98".